# JQuery Drag/Drop Disallow multiple list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have two containers in top and bottom,

I'm adding list of text from bottom container to top container using jquery draggable operation as of now its working fine,

but one small change in my scenario currently now multiple records are adding to my top container i want only once, no multiple/same list record should appear in top container

**say for example**

if i have one record placed above in top container next time if i drag same list record to top container it should not be added into top container either record should be disabled after adding list record or no duplicate record should be allowed in top container

somebody help me out in achieving it Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/t0ndh136/1/

**Html**

```
<div class="drop_list">
        <ol id="sortable" style="list-style:decimal;">
            <li id='item1' class="draggable_li qitem">
                <span class="item">Item = 1</span>
            </li>
            <li id='item2' class="draggable_li qitem">
                <span class="item">Item = 2</span>
            </li>
            <li id='item3' class="draggable_li qitem">
                <span class="item">Item = 3</span>
            </li>
            <li id='item4' class="draggable_li qitem">
                <span class="item">Item = 4</span>
            </li>           
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="sort_list">
    <ul id="draggable">
        <li id='item1' class="draggable_li qitem">
            <span class="item">Item Dragged = 1</span>
        </li>
        <li id='item2' class="draggable_li qitem">
            <span class="item">Item Dragged = 2</span>
        </li>
        <li id='item3' class="draggable_li qitem">
            <span class="item">Item Dragged = 3</span>
        </li>
        <li id='item4' class="draggable_li qitem">
            <span class="item">Item Dragged = 4</span>
        </li>   
        <li id='item5' class="draggable_li qitem">
            <span class="item">Item Dragged = 5</span>
        </li>       
    </ul>
    </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#sortable").sortable({
            revert: true,
            helper : 'clone',
            revert :10          
        });


        $("ol li").disableSelection();

        $(".sort_list li").draggable({

            tolerance:"pointer",
            helper : 'clone',
            refreshPositions: true ,
            revert : 'invalid',
            opacity:.4,
            connectToSortable: '#sortable'
        });


    });
```

Comment: Why can't you remove the item which was dragged from the bottom list?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Mosh Feu!